# Too fast movement Blender 2.8

Tags: animation

If I rotate with middle mouse button I move so much to fast. I rotate around a point somewehre. How I can rotate around the active object? Shift + F doesn't work. Thank you four our help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the user preferences **edit - preferences** you go to **navigation**, and then under **orbit and pan** check **orbit around selection**.  this will make you rotate around whatever object you have selected.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but now is the rotation good but the Middlemouse + Shift is still too fast how I can fix that too?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that, is this a problem with all your blend files, or just this one?

Comment: try selecting one of your objects, and pressing **numpad period**.  This should help.

Comment: Thank you so mich Millard now is the movement good.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you want, you can probably turn off orbit around the selection, if you prefer a global orbit pivot.